# Generating random numbers from two different intervals in R

Tags: r, random

To generate randomly distributed values in a single range, I use:

```
runif(number_of_numbers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

However, what if I want to generate randomly distributed values **in two different intervals**?

For example, I want to generate 100 random values between [-3,-2] and [2,3].
Is there an one-line elegant solution for that?

Comment: `runif(100, 2, 3) * sign(rnorm(100))` or simply `runif(100, 2, 3) * c(-1, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My one-liner solution is as follows, however there might be an elegant solution better than this:

```
sample(c(runif(100,-3,-2),runif(100,2,3)),100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ifelse(runif(100)>0.5,1,-1)*runif(100,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the wonderful thing called list. You can use functions on them. This streamlines so much. Another advantage you can keep your results in a list.

```r
ls_iv <- list(iv1 = -3:-2, iv2 = 2:3)

lapply(ls_iv, function(x) runif(100, x[1], x[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that works for any two intervals (a_1, b_1) and (a_2, b_2), go with something like:

```
n <- 100
a1 <- -3; b1 <- -2
a2 <- 2; b2 <- 3

ifelse(rbinom(n, 1, 0.5), runif(n, a1, b1), runif(n, a2, b2))
```